# Another user's edit is pending alert is not showing in Review | First Post and Review | Late Answer page

Tags: bug, edits

In **Review | First Post and Review | Late Answer** pages, if I feel to edit the question or answer to improve its quality, and I click the edit, I am not getting the below alert:

[image: Screenshot]

And nothing is happening if someone already has submitted an edit for approval when I click the edit option.

Comment: and of [Editing a post during review doesn't show an 'edit not possible' message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/295232)